# SMPlayer hotkey to jump to the beginning of the video

Tags: video, keyboard-shortcuts

I can't find a hotkey in SMPlayer to navigate to the beginning of the video. I have to push the hotkey for going 1 minute backward and to keep it pushed until it gets to the beginning of the video.

Is there a fix?